# Input password Blazor forms

Tags: .net, blazor

I am adding a form in Blazor and I am following instructions as specified here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Is it possible to add an input with mask for passwords.

I tried adding doing something like

```
public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

but that didnt work. Is there a way to hide password when inserted in input?

Comment: <input type="password"

Comment: so what are the benefits of using EditForm component instead of good old html

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the `InputText` component with `type=password`:

```cs
<EditForm Model="@model">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <InputText type="password" placeholder="Password" @bind-Value="@model.Password" />
</EditForm>

@code {
    class Login
    {
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    private Login model = new Login();
}
```

The `InputText` support all `<input />` attributes

Comment: Is there anyway we can validate if user input password and confirm password as same text? I can do that with custom code after submit but i want EditForm do it and blazor handle the red border and other stuff

Comment: Use the Compare Attribute from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirm password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }